# Why is the sort method not working on this custom AbstractList implementation?

Tags: java, android, list

Android Studio is giving me a "Usage of API documented as @since 1.8+" error on the `sort()` line, inside the `addAll()` method. I'm not quite sure what this means...

All I want to do is a custom `List` where I can sort the `List` by the `publishedAt` property of `Articles_Map`.

**AbstractArticlesList**:

```
public class AbstractArticlesList extends AbstractList<Articles_Map> {
    private final List<Articles_Map> l;

    public AbstractArticlesList() {
        l = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Articles_Map get(int index) {
        return l.get(index);
    }

    public Articles_Map set(int index, Articles_Map element) {
        Articles_Map oldValue = l.get(index);
        l.add(index, element);
        return oldValue;
    }

    public int size() {
        return l.size();
    }

    private void doAdd(Articles_Map another) {
        l.add(another);
    }

    public void addAll(List<Articles_Map> others) {
        for (Articles_Map a : others) {
            doAdd(a);
        }
        l.sort(byPublishedAtComparator);
    }

    private final Comparator<Articles_Map> byPublishedAtComparator =
            new Comparator<Articles_Map>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Articles_Map o1, Articles_Map o2) {
                    if (o1.publishedAt == null) {
                        return (o2.publishedAt == null) ? 0 : -1;
                    } else if (o2.publishedAt == null) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    return o1.publishedAt.compareTo(o2.publishedAt);
                }
            };
}
```

**Articles_Map**:

```
public class Articles_Map {
    public final String title;
    public final String description;
    public final String url;
    public final String urlToImage;
    public final Date publishedAt;

    public Articles_Map(String title, String description, String url, String urlToImage, Date publishedAt) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.url = url;
        this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
        this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be done if you moved the compareFunction to the AbstractArticlesList class insted of the inner...? And maybe add implements comparably to the AbstractArticlesList class.

Comment: Note that a self-sorting `List` violates the `List` contract.  Really, this shouldn't _be_ a `List` but should _have_ a `List` with a normal implementation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`sort()` is new to API Level 24](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort(java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20E%3E)) (Android 7.0), courtesy of Android starting to adopt bits of Java 1.8.

[Use `Collections.sort()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E)) if your `minSdkVersion` is lower than 24.

Comment: Thanks, this combined with Louis Wasserman's suggestion did the trick.